# centreon_plugins ignore with regexp

Tags: linux, monitoring, regex-negation, inode

how can I ignore or filter parts of the result of centreon_plugins.pl using a regexp ?

practical example :

I'm trying to monitor inodes on all my linux servers (RHEL 6) so I use the following command:

```
perl centreon_plugins.pl --plugin=os::linux::snmp::plugin --mode=inodes --hostname=servname --snmp-version=2c --snmp-community=mycomm --warning 80 --critical 90 --name --regexp --verbose
```

This will give me all inodes on all filesystem, but it will always be in alarm due, for example, to /proc
Also, this will monitor my home dir that are mounted on a nfs share.

So i want to exclude a couple of strings like home, proc, ...

If I try to use this :

```
perl centreon_plugins.pl --plugin=os::linux::snmp::plugin --mode=inodes --hostname=servname --snmp-version=2c --snmp-community=mycomm --warning 80 --critical 90 --name --regexp --diskpath=/?!proc/ --verbose
```

I'll get an error like this :

```
-bash: !proc: event not found
```

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right syntax is :

```
--diskpath='^(?!(/proc)$)'
```

To exlcude multiple FileSysyems :

```
--diskpath='^(?!(/proc.*|/sys|/dev/pts|/var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs)$)'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `--diskpath=/?!proc/` must be quoted. Bash interprets the character !

Try:

```
perl centreon_plugins.pl --plugin=os::linux::snmp::plugin --mode=inodes --hostname=servname --snmp-version=2c --snmp-community=mycomm --warning 80 --critical 90 --name --regexp "--diskpath=/?!proc/" --verbose
```

Comment: Hi, same error while trying with double quotes, no error with simple quotes but the regexp doesn't work:  No disk path found for name '/?!proc/'